# Make command line aliases reveal the true command (Mac)

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

I've already created a bunch of aliases in a file that my `~/.zshrc` imports, such as:

```
alias sl='git status -uall'
```

When I run my aliases (such as `sl`) in Terminal, they work as expected.

However, I'd *love* if *before running their command* they would print the commmand itself that they're about to run.

E.g. when I type `sl` and press Return, it would be great if I then saw in the Terminal `git status -uall` and then the output of that command.

That way, I'd continually be reminding myself of what my aliases stand for.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 5):

One idea would be to just add a call to `alias` to the start of your definition:

```
$ alias foo='alias foo; echo bar'
$ foo
alias foo='alias foo; echo bar'
bar
```

The closest `bash` has to automatically printing the value of an alias is to use the `xtrace` option (though that outputs *every* command to standard error as it is executed).

You can also bind the Readline command `alias-expand-line` to some key.

```
bind '"\C-x\C-a": alias-expand-line'
```

Now typing Control-x, Control-a sometime before typing Enter will cause `bash` to perform alias expansion on the current command line in-place, letting you see, edit, and/or abort the resulting command before executing it.